# Finding damages in image using feature matching

Tags: c++, opencv, feature-extraction, feature-detection, orb

Given an image and a template image, I would like to match the images and find **possible damages, if any**.

**Undamaged Image**

[image: **Original Image**]

**Damaged Image**

[image: **Damaged Image**]

**Template Image**

[image: **Template Image**]

**Note**: Above image shows the example of a damage, which can be of any size and shape. Assume that proper preprocessing has been done and both the template and the image are converted to binary with a white background.

I used the following approach to detect the key points and match it:

1. Find all the `keypoints` and the `descriptors` from the template as well as the image using **ORB**.  For that, I used the inbuilt function of **OpenCV** named `detectAndCompute()`.
2. After this, I used the Brute Force Matcher and matched it using the `knnMatch()`.
3. Then I used the `Lowe's Ratio Test` to find good matches.

**Results:**
If I match the template with itself `template-template`, I get **1751** matches which should be an ideal value for a perfect match.

In the undamaged image, I got **847** good matches.

[image: **Matches on Undamaged Image**]

In the damaged image, I got **346** good matches.

[image: **Matches on the Damaged Image**]

We can perceive the differences from the number of matches, but I have a few questions:

1. **How to pin point the exact location of the damages?**
2. How can I conclude that the image contains damages by looking at the number of good matches in the `image-template` and `template-template`?

**P.S.:** I am expecting an elaborate answer as I am new to OpenCV.

**EDIT:** Here is the code for your reference.

```
    #include <iostream>

    #include <opencv2/features2d/features2d.hpp>
    #include <opencv2/calib3d/calib3d.hpp>
    #include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
    #include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>

    using namespace std;
    using namespace cv;

    int main() {

            Mat image = imread("./Images/PigeonsDamaged.jpg");
            Mat temp = imread("./Templates/Pigeons.bmp");

            Mat img_gray, temp_gray;

            cvtColor(image, img_gray, CV_RGB2GRAY);
            cvtColor(temp, temp_gray, CV_RGB2GRAY);

            /**** Pre-processing *****/

            threshold(temp_gray, temp_gray, 200, 255, THRESH_BINARY);
            adaptiveThreshold(img_gray, img_gray, 255, ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, THRESH_BINARY_INV, 221, 0);

            /*****/

            /***** ORB keypoint detector *****/

            Mat img_descriptors, temp_descriptors;
            vector<KeyPoint> img_keypoints, temp_keypoints;

            vector<KeyPoint> &img_kp = img_keypoints;
            vector<KeyPoint> &temp_kp = temp_keypoints;

            Ptr<ORB> orb = ORB::create(100000, 1.2f, 4, 40, 0, 4, ORB::HARRIS_SCORE, 40, 20);

            orb -> detectAndCompute(img_gray, noArray(), img_kp, img_descriptors, false);
            orb -> detectAndCompute(temp_gray, noArray(), temp_kp, temp_descriptors, false);

            cout << "Temp Keypoints " << temp_kp.size() << endl;

            /*****/

            vector<vector<DMatch> > featureMatches;
            vector<vector<DMatch> > &matches = featureMatches;

            Mat & img_desc_ref = img_descriptors;
            Mat & temp_desc_ref = temp_descriptors;

            BFMatcher bf(NORM_HAMMING2, false);    /** Never keep crossCheck true when using knnMatch. Imp: Use NORM_HAMMING2 for WTA_K = 3 or 4 **/
            bf.knnMatch(img_descriptors, temp_descriptors, matches, 3);

            /*****/

            /***** Ratio Test *****/

            vector<DMatch> selected;
            vector<Point2f> src_pts, temp_pts;

            float testRatio = 0.75;

            for (int i = 0; i < featureMatches.size(); ++i) {

                    if (featureMatches[i][0].distance < testRatio * featureMatches[i][1].distance) {
                            selected.push_back(featureMatches[i][0]);
                    }

            }


            cout << "Selected Size: " << selected.size() << endl;

            /*****/

            /*** Draw the Feature Matches ***/

            Mat output;
            vector <DMatch> &priorityMatches = selected;

            drawMatches(image, img_kp, temp, temp_kp, priorityMatches, output, Scalar(0, 255, 0), Scalar::all(-1));

            namedWindow("Output", CV_WINDOW_FREERATIO);
            imshow("Output", output);
            waitKey();

            /******/

            return 0;
    }
```

Comment: can you share your code with us? If so, It will be easier for us to help.

Comment: why did you choose keypoint matching? Since most of the image is undamaged, keypoints in those regions will still match very good. I would suggest two steps: 1. align the image to the template with keypoint matching. 2. something like chamfer matching applied on "blocks" within the image to find regions that differ more from the template than other blocks within the image.

Comment: @Micka The above image is just an example of a damage. It can vary a lot.

Comment: @SiddharthKamaria my suggestion is still the same (without seeing images where it shouldn't work)

Comment: @drorco I have added the code!

Comment: about your concrete questions: "How can I conclude that the image contains damages by looking at the number of good matches" - test your method for a database of damaged and undamaged images. Plot the number of matched features and the number of features in the template. But I doubt that you can find a good threshold or ratio that works for "all" images and templates.

Comment: @Micka Ya, I am not able to find a generic threshold for different images.